# Oracle stats type and unit

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, statistics, view

I need your help, i have to know the type (e.g: time, quantity, etc...) and the unit (e.g: seconds, byte, etc...) of all the stats in the *V$STATNAME* views, can anyone help me? I'm using **Oracle 11g** (11.2.0.1).

I tried searching the web for an official manual or something like this, but i found nothing...

Here's all the stats:

```
OS CPU Qt wait time

logons cumulative

logons current

opened cursor cumulative

opened cursor current

user commits

user rollbacks

user calls

recursive calls

recursive cpu usage

pinned cursor current

session logical reads

session stored procedure space 

cpu used when call started

cpu used by this session

DB time

cluster wait time

concurrency wait time

application wait time
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/stats002.htm#i375475)?

Comment: unfortunately this is not the thing i'm looking for...

for example logons current is reporting this, and not the type and unit... :(

'logons current
1
Total number of current logons. Useful only in V$SYSSTAT.'

Comment: How so? The linked page is the official documentation for `V$SESSTAT` and `V$SYSSTAT` which supply the data for `V$STATNAME`.

Comment: So, how can i find the information i'm looking for? where can i find the unit of OS CPU Qt wait time, for example?  I know that is a time just because it have the "time" word in the name, but is it in seconds? milliseconds? microseconds? hours? minutes? and what about "logons current" that don't have the "time" or "quantity" word in the name? i'm really confsed...

Comment: You can check Tom Kyte and others. But you probably have a reason to ask for this documentation (I've been searching in the past a lot for exactly the same). What is the problem that requires information on these data dictionary fields?